# If $\mathbb E X = \infty$, is $\mathbb P(\overline X_n > \alpha)$ increasing?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Question**

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be i.i.d. random variables with $X_1 \geq 0$ and $\mathbb EX = \infty$.

Denote the sample mean by $\overline X_n := \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Does it follow that $\mathbb P(\overline X_n > \alpha)$ is a non-decreasing sequence in $n$, where $\alpha$ is any real number?

If not, how about for $n > N$ for some sufficiently large $N$?

---

**Thoughts**

I know that $\overline X_n \to \infty$ almost surely. Applying dominated convergence, we then have $\mathbb P(\overline X_n > \alpha) \to 1$ for any $\alpha$. But I'm trying to figure out how to show that the second limit increases monotonically.

I've tried some rearranging of the following sort, where $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $F_X$ is the distribution function of $X$,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} X_i > (n+1)\alpha \right) &= \mathbb P\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i > (n+1)\alpha - X_{n+1} \right) \\
&= \mathbb E \left[ \mathbb P \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i > n \alpha - (X_{n+1}-\alpha) \middle| X_{n+1} \right) \right] \\
&= 1 - \mathbb E F_{S_n}\Big(n\alpha - (X_{n+1} - \alpha) \Big)
\end{align}
$$
So it would be equivalent to show $\mathbb E F_{S_n}\Big(n\alpha - [X_{n+1} - \alpha] \Big) \leq F_{S_n}(n\alpha)$. But this approach hasn't been fruitful so far.

Comment: Why do yo think it should be true? If $X_{n+1}\leq \overline{X_n}$ then $\overline{X_{n+1}}\leq \overline{X_n}$. This shows that with some positive probability it may so happen that $\overline{X_n}>\alpha$ but $\overline{X_{n+1}}\leq \alpha$.